# Retorno de valor 'undefined' por causa do assincronismo

Tags: node.js

Possuo um arquivo chamado `validationForgetPassword.js` com o seguinte codigo:

```
"use strict"

var config = require('./config'),
    createHash = require('sha.js'),
    pgPromise = require('./pgPromise'),
    winston = require('./winston');

module.exports = function (id, time, hashForgetPassword) {
    var date = new Date();
    date = date.getTime();

    if (date > time) {
        logger.log('error', 'date expirated');
        return null;
    }

     pgPromise.db.oneOrNone('select dr_email, dr_tax_id, dr_license, dr_first_name, dr_last_name, dr_cell_phone from driver where dr_id = ($1)', [id])
    .then(function (results) {
        if (results) {
            results.time = time;
            var result = JSON.stringify(results);

            var sha256 = createHash('sha256')
            var hash = sha256.update(result, 'utf8').digest('hex');

            console.log(hash);
            console.log(hashForgetPassword);

            if(hashForgetPassword === hash) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                logger.log('error', 'hash is not valid');
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            logger.log('error', 'Not result in select driver');
            return null;
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        logger.log('error', 'Error in select driver from module validationForgetPassword \n' + error);
        return null;
    });
}
```

E um `server.js` com o seguinte código:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors');
    path = require ('path');

var login = require('./api/routes/login'),
    logoff = require('./api/routes/logoff'),
    forgetPasswordUser = require('./api/routes/forgetPasswordUser');
    importEvents = require('./api/routes/importEvents'),
    taskWorker = require('./api/routes/taskWorker'),
    create = require('./api/routes/create'),
    validationForgetPassword = require('./config/validationForgetPassword');
    winston = require('./config/winston');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.set('views', __dirname + '/api/views');

new winston();
importEvents();
taskWorker();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use('/api/v1/driver/login', login);
app.use('/api/v1/driver/logoff', logoff);
app.use('/api/v1/driver/create', create);
app.use('/forgetPasswordUser', forgetPasswordUser);

app.get('/forgetPassword/:id/:time/:hash', function(req, res) {

    const id = req.params.id;
    const time = req.params.time;
    const hash = req.params.hash;

    var token;
    token = validationForgetPassword(id, time, hash);

    if (token == 1) { 
        res.render('pages/forgetPassword');
    } else {
    //res.render('pages/forgetPassword/oi');
    }
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('API started on port ' + port);
```

Porém, o resultado volta undefined, pois ele executa o if antes do retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é de assíncronismo. Há várias perguntas aqui que referem isso em Ajax por exemplo. Neste caso com Promises é basicamente o mesmo.

Assim no teu módulo podes usar `callbacks` à moda antiga ou uma Promise. Aqui fica um exemplo com Promise. Repara na parte `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`

```
"use strict"

var config = require('./config'),
    createHash = require('sha.js'),
    pgPromise = require('./pgPromise'),
    winston = require('./winston');

module.exports = function(id, time, hashForgetPassword) {
    var date = new Date();
    date = date.getTime();

    if (date > time) {
        logger.log('error', 'date expirated');
        return null;
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pgPromise.db.oneOrNone('select dr_email, dr_tax_id, dr_license, dr_first_name, dr_last_name, dr_cell_phone from driver where dr_id = ($1)', [id])
            .then(function(results) {
                if (results) {
                    results.time = time;
                    var result = JSON.stringify(results);

                    var sha256 = createHash('sha256')
                    var hash = sha256.update(result, 'utf8').digest('hex');

                    console.log(hash);
                    console.log(hashForgetPassword);

                    if (hashForgetPassword === hash) return resolve(1);
                    logger.log('error', 'hash is not valid');
                    reject('hash is not valid');
                } else {
                    logger.log('error', 'Not result in select driver');
                    reject('Not result in select driver');
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                logger.log('error', 'Error in select driver from module validationForgetPassword \n' + error);
            });
    });

}
```

e no ficheiro que requer esse módulo podes fazer:

```
var validationForgetPassword = require('./config/validationForgetPassword');
// ...

app.get('/forgetPassword/:id/:time/:hash', function(req, res) {

    const id = req.params.id;
    const time = req.params.time;
    const hash = req.params.hash;

    validationForgetPassword(id, time, hash).then(token => {
        if (token == 1) res.render('pages/forgetPassword');
        else res.render('pages/forgetPassword/oi');
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
        res.redirect('/')
    });
});
```

Dessa maneira `validationForgetPassword` transforma-se numa promise quando invocada e podes usar o `then` que vai receber como argumento o que lhe passares ao `resolve`.